# How to change Backend Theano to TensionFlow in keras Unix

Tags: unix, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, theano

After reading many blogs I tried  ~/.keras/keras.json, but got error 
bash: /home/user/.keras/keras.json: Permission denied

Comment: did you ever run keras with sudo?

Comment: no, what do you mean by that? what will happen and what is the command?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official documentation You can define the environment variable KERAS_BACKEND and this will override what is defined in your config file.

`KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow python -c "from keras import backend"`

Or you can use nano to edit keras.json file from command line. i.e 
`nano $HOME/.keras/keras.json`.

Comment: I did that but it still uses theano